# DB2 locking when no record yet exists

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table, something like:

```
create table state {foo int not null, bar int not null, baz varchar(32)};
create unique index on state(foo,bar);
```

I'd like to lock for a unique record in this table. However, if there's no existing record I'd like to prevent anyone else from inserting a record, but without inserting myself.

I'd use "FOR UPDATE WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS" but that only seems to work if the record exists.

Comment: Are you talking about DB2 security? are you talking about concurrency?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to allocate a primary key value that no one else could use?

Comment: @AngocA - concurrency.

Comment: @WarrenT - correct, I want to prevent some else inserting into the table while I'm working on the data I want to insert

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: You should tell us some more about *why* you are doing this - what you are trying to achieve. There may be other, perhaps better solutions to your problem, for example DB2 Sequences[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0023175.html].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) You can let DB2 create every ID number.  Let's say you have defined your Customer table

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
( CustomerID       Int          NOT NULL
                                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                                PRIMARY KEY
, Name             Varchar(50)
, Billing_Type     Char(1) 
, Balance          Dec(9,2)     NOT NULL DEFAULT 
);
```

Insert rows without specifying the CustomerID, since DB2 will always produce the value for you.

```
INSERT INTO Customers 
    (Name, Billing_Type)
  VALUES
    (:cname, :billtype);
```

If you need to know what the last value assigned in your session was, you can then use the `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()` function.

B) In my environment, I generally specify `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`.  This is in part due to the nature of our principle programming language, ILE RPG-IV, where developers have traditionally to allowed the compiler to use the entire record definition.  This leads me to I can tell everyone to use a [sequence](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzseqref.htm) to generate ID values for a given table or set of tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant select to only you, but if there are others with secadm or other privileges, they could insert.

You can do something with a trigger, something like check the current session, and if the user is your user, then it inserts the row.

```
if (SESSION_USER <> 'Alex) then
  rollback -- or generate an exception
end if;
```

It seems that you also want to keep just one row, then, you can control that also in a trigger:

```
select count(0) into value from state
if (value > 1) then
  rollback -- or generate an exception
end if;
```